# Node.js script works once, then fails subsequently

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

> I need a Node.js script that does the following:
>
> 1 - Triggers when an image is added to a specified S3 bucket.
>  2
>   - Creates a thumbnail of that image (360x203 pixels).
>  3 - Saves a copy of that thumbnail inside of a separate S3 folder.
>  4 -
>   Uploads the thumbnail to a specified FTP server, SIX (6) times using a
>   "FILENAME-X"naming convention.

The code works just as expected at first. The sample event pulls the image. Creates a thumnail. Saves it to the other S3 bucket. Then uploads it to the FTP server.

**The problem:** It works for the test file HappyFace.jpg once, but then each subsequent test fails. Also, I tried doing it with a different file, but was unsuccessful.

Also: If I could get some help writing a loop to name the different files that get uploaded, it would be very much appreciated. I usually code in PHP, so it'd probably take me longer than I hope to write.

Note: I removed my FTP credentials for privacy.

**Problem Code Snippet:**

```
    function upload(contentType, data, next) {
        // Upload test file to FTP server
        c.append(data, 'testing.jpg', function(err) {
            console.log("CONNECTION SUCCESS!");
            if (err) throw err;
            c.end();
        });
        // Connect to ftp
        c.connect({
            host: "",
            port: 21, // defaults to 21
            user: "", // defaults to "anonymous"
            password: "" // defaults to "@anonymous"
        });
        // S3 Bucket Upload Function Goes Here
    }
```

**Full Code:**

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var util = require('util');
var Client = require('ftp');
var fs = require('fs');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.

// get reference to FTP client
var c = new Client();
// get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    // Get source bucket
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Get source object key
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));  
    var url = 'http://' + srcBucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com/" + srcKey;
    // Set destination bucket
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "-thumbs";
    // Set destination object key
    var dstKey    = "resized-" + srcKey;

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        console.error('unable to infer image type for key ' + srcKey);
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        console.log('skipping non-image ' + srcKey);
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Upload test file to FTP server
            c.append(data, 'testing.jpg', function(err) {
                console.log("CONNECTION SUCCESS!");
                if (err) throw err;
                c.end();
            });
            // Connect to ftp
            c.connect({
                host: "",
                port: 21, // defaults to 21
                user: "", // defaults to "anonymous"
                password: "" // defaults to "@anonymous"
            });
            // Stream the thumb image to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
        }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

//          context.done();
        }
    );
};
```

**The logs:**

```
START RequestId: edc808c1-712b-11e5-aa8a-ed7c188ee86c Version: $LATEST 
2015-10-12T21:55:20.481Z    edc808c1-712b-11e5-aa8a-ed7c188ee86c    Reading options from event: { Records:  [ { eventVersion: '2.0', eventTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', requestParameters: { sourceIPAddress: '127.0.0.1' }, s3:  { configurationId: 'testConfigRule', object:  { eTag: '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef', sequencer: '0A1B2C3D4E5F678901', key: 'HappyFace.jpg', size: 1024 }, bucket:  { arn: 'arn:aws:s3:::images', name: 'images', ownerIdentity: { principalId: 'EXAMPLE' } }, s3SchemaVersion: '1.0' }, responseElements:  { 'x-amz-id-2': 'EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH', 'x-amz-request-id': 'EXAMPLE123456789' }, awsRegion: 'us-east-1', eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put', userIdentity: { principalId: 'EXAMPLE' }, eventSource: 'aws:s3' } ] } 
2015-10-12T21:55:22.411Z    edc808c1-712b-11e5-aa8a-ed7c188ee86c    Successfully resized images/HappyFace.jpg and uploaded to images-thumbs/resized-HappyFace.jpg 
2015-10-12T21:55:23.432Z    edc808c1-712b-11e5-aa8a-ed7c188ee86c    CONNECTION SUCCESS! 
END RequestId: edc808c1-712b-11e5-aa8a-ed7c188ee86c 
REPORT RequestId: edc808c1-712b-11e5-aa8a-ed7c188ee86c  Duration: 3003.76 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 43 MB   
Task timed out after 3.00 seconds  
START RequestId: d347e7e3-712d-11e5-bfdf-05baa36d50fd Version: $LATEST 
2015-10-12T22:08:55.910Z    d347e7e3-712d-11e5-bfdf-05baa36d50fd    Reading options from event: { Records:  [ { eventVersion: '2.0', eventTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', requestParameters: { sourceIPAddress: '127.0.0.1' }, s3:  { configurationId: 'testConfigRule', object:  { eTag: '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef', sequencer: '0A1B2C3D4E5F678901', key: 'HappyFace.jpg', size: 1024 }, bucket:  { arn: 'arn:aws:s3:::images', name: 'images', ownerIdentity: { principalId: 'EXAMPLE' } }, s3SchemaVersion: '1.0' }, responseElements:  { 'x-amz-id-2': 'EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH', 'x-amz-request-id': 'EXAMPLE123456789' }, awsRegion: 'us-east-1', eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put', userIdentity: { principalId: 'EXAMPLE' }, eventSource: 'aws:s3' } ] } 
END RequestId: d347e7e3-712d-11e5-bfdf-05baa36d50fd 
REPORT RequestId: d347e7e3-712d-11e5-bfdf-05baa36d50fd  Duration: 3003.33 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 17 MB   
Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Comment: Sorry, is that the wrong term? Module? It's an AWS Lambda function,.

Comment: "Script" doesn't have a precise definition but usually refers to a small program, maybe just a few lines. But you're describing a large application.

Comment: Oh gotcha, it's pretty small compared to what I usually work on. But did you have any ideas about where to look for the bug?  I was thinking it could be caused by it not closing the FTP connection. Because I just ran the script again, and it worked just fine. Which makes me think it had to wait for something to timeout.

Comment: Your question is *really* general. Can you please narrow it down to one thing that you are working on, with a code sample that shows just the one thing and where it is failing?

Comment: It is failing at the "upload" function.  **c.append** to be specific. That is what uploads the file to the FTP server. **c.connect** is what opens the connection to the FTP server. How should I add the code sample to this question? (Sorry, this is my first time posting a question).

Comment: I don’t see this being uploaded 6 times from the code you posted, and I don’t know how your FTP client works, but: your `var c = new Client()` only gets executed *once*, so all calls to `handler` are using the same instance of the client. If you have potentially overlapping calls, it would be a problem. For example, `c.end()` from a previous upload could terminate another in-progress upload.

Comment: @Nero I ran into a similar issue when writing a complex function that would create multiple pdfs and then email them to users. My theory was then when requiring my module, the node module cache would cache my variables and mess things up. What I did to fix it was rather than require the module I put the function into my route callback.

Comment: @Nate You're correct. It currently doesn't upload 6 times, I didn't code it yet to eliminate variables. I was thinking of using a loop around the **c.append** function to do that.

Comment: @Nate Are you saying that if the Lambda function executes a second time, while the first is still uploading (say it's a large file). Then it would cause the first upload to terminate early?

Comment: @realseanp I'd like to give that a try. How would I go about doing that? I'm a little unclear about what you mean. Should I also move the `var c = new Client();` down into the upload function?

Comment: @Nero Yes. You should probably create a new `Client()` for each upload. That may also fail if your FTP server limits the number of simultaneous connections. In that case, you may want to use a queue (like `async.queue`) — that gets a bit more complex and probably warrants opening another question.

Comment: @Nate Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with `async.queue` I'll look at the documentation. I know for a fact the server limits simultaneous connections to 3. So that's definitely going to need to be in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
var c = new Client();
```

is only going to get executed once; all calls to your `handler()` function will use the same instance of your FTP client.

If there could be multiple overlapping calls to `handler()`—and in an async world it sure seems likely—then the calls to the FTP client, including `c.connect(…)` and `c.end()` will be invoked multiple times against the *same* FTP client, which may already have an upload in progress, leading to a scenario like this:

1. Call to `handler()`. Upload begins.
2. Call to `handler()`. Second upload begins.
3. First upload completes and calls `c.end()`.
4. Second upload is canceled.

The solution is to create a new FTP client instance for each upload or, if your FTP server has a problem with that (limits the number of client connections), you’ll need to serialize your uploads somehow. One way to do that, since you’re using the `async` library, would be to use [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue).

Comment: Also, besides the concurrency issues, `c.end()` kills the connection so that's another reason that a `new Client()` object has to be created for each upload.